# how to make json with same key different value in java

Tags: java, json

i'm trying to make a function

reading from specific directory and make a json file with that file's title in directory.

it reads file's title well but when i print out, it overlaps again and again

i need same key name and different value.

is there any way to put a number on key name or make same key?

```
bullet01.png
{"file":"bullet01.png"}
bullet011.png
{"file":"bullet011.png"}
bullet012.png
{"file":"bullet012.png"}
bullet013.png
{"file":"bullet013.png"}
bullet02.png
{"file":"bullet02.png"}
```

this is a full code

```
public void downloadFile(ViewMeta view) throws IOException {

        DataSet input = view.getInputDataSet();

    HttpServletRequest request = view.getHttpServletRequest();
    String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/curriculum1.4/filedir");
    DataSet output = new DataSet();
    File dir = new File(filePath);
    String files[] = dir.list();
    JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
    for(String fn : files) {
        System.out.println(fn);
        data.put("file", fn);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    view.setAttribute("file", data);
    view.printJSON();
}
```

this is a setAttribute structure

```
   public void setAttribute(String key, Object val) {
        if (this.keyList == null) {
            this.keyList = new ArrayList();
        }

        this.keyList.add(key);
        this.request.setAttribute(key, val);
        this.request.setAttribute("coreframe.object.keyList", this.keyList);
    }
```

Comment: you need to have a json array with multiple json objects.. each object can then have the "file" key.. I suggest you to learn more about json, then come up with a json that you want and validate it in some online validator to check if it's correct.. because what you posted above is invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want same key and have different value, you can make it as `JSONArray` format.

```
[{"file" : "bullet01.png"}, {"file" : "bullet02.png"}, {"file" : "bullet03.png"}]
```

your code may need to change like this :

```
.....
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(String fn : files) {
    //create json object for each file
    JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
    System.out.println(fn);
    data.put("file", fn);
    System.out.println(data);
    //put json object into json array
    array.put(data); 
}
view.setAttribute("file", array);
view.printJSON();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the keys in the JSON should be unique. You can try appending numbers at the end of the key "file"